# The lowest possible video streaming latency over a LAN?

Tags: video-streaming, lan, latency

I would like to know what can be the lowest possible video streaming over a LAN? Imagine I need to create a LAN for about 50 clients (all physically in a diameter of 2 meters) and a hub/switch with 1000-based Ethernet, which that 10 clients are the HD-SDI cameras would like to stream thier video frames at the same time. I do not mind to use any off-the-schelf encoder HW and/or any streaming protocol HW. What can be the lowest possible latency of one of selected video-clients when displaying in the other client side (screen)? Imagin also that the cameras stand-alone latencies including encoder are about 20 ms and the display latency including decoder is 10 ms.

Comment: Hello welcome to the community but propably this is not the right one for the question ...  You could try https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related. This is highly dependable on network hardware and its physical capabilities.

Comment: Ethernet really isn't the tool for this job.  You actually need to genlock those cameras if you actually want them to create frames at the same time.